# Dos proyectos o dos módulos en Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular9

tengo un proyecto que se conecta a una api de laravel, y trae artículos, el usuario los puede ver y votar solamente, nada mas. Este proyecto consta de un modulo angular con sus componentes, css, js (tiene algunos ya que es una plantilla ya desarrollada).
Hasta ahí todo bien, ahora resulta que necesito tener usuarios administradores, que se loguean y cargan esos artículos, esta con otra plantilla bootrap 4.
La pregunta es, **este administrador debería ser un proyecto nuevo de angular?** **o**
**Debería ser otro modulo con otro archivo index llamado por ejemplo admin.html que use dicho modulo?**
Que se acostumbra a hacer en estos casos, la segunda opción te hace ahorrar tiempo ya que el proyecto está creado y configurado, la opción uno permite la compilación, la publicación mas rápida al estar desdoblado en dos, pero hay que crear quizá mas configuraciones...
Cual seria la mejor opción?
Muchas gracias

[image: Mi proyecto]

Comment: Lo ideal es un solo proyecto y estructurarlo de tal forma que se permitan diferentes funciones basadas en los roles de los usuarios. En este momento se introducirá el rol ADMIN y que tal después aparece un rol X? No se va a crear otro proyecto para ese nuevo rol. Solo debería crearse el rol y configurar a donde puede ingresar y listo, el mismo sistema con diferentes configuraciones.

Comment: Y no hacer un módulo por cada rol sino que un módulo para agrupar funciones similares del sistema. Por ejemplo un sistema empresarial puede tener un módulo para contabilidad, otro para recursos humanos, otro para administración etc. Y según el rol del usuario así puede entrar a funciones específicas de ese módulo.

Comment: En realidad no es el rol admin, es un administrador del sitio, si surgen roles, los tendrían estos usuarios de este administrador.
El usuario visitante no tiene roles, todos pueden hacer lo mismo, ni deberían ver en ningún lado la pantalla de login...
Por otro lado al tener al agregar la plantilla nueva del administrador, esta contiene nuevos assets, nuevos css, js, etc... esto también es una contra porque  serian mas assets para el proyecto, mas entradas en el archivo angular.json.
En fin tiene sus pro y sus contras cada una de las soluciones...

Comment: Como podría hacer para en un proyecto tener un modulo llamado appModule que sea cargado cuando navego el index.html
y otro modulo llamado adminModule que se cargue cuando ejecuto admin.html
Ambos htmls en el mismo proyecto, en la raiz de este?

Answer (score 1):

Angular define dos herramientas que resuelven este problema.

[Guards con `canActive`](https://angular.io/guide/router#preventing-unauthorized-access)

> Usa un guardia de ruta (guards route) para prevenir a los usuarios navegar a partes de la aplicación que requiera autorización.

[Lazy load](https://angular.io/guide/router#preventing-unauthorized-access)

> La carga perezosa optimiza la obtención de recursos de la aplicación permitiendo descargar  en demanda lo que el usuario vaya solicitando.

La mezcla de estas dos herramientas permite que por un lado no se active las rutas para las cuales el usuario no tiene permiso y por otro, que no descargue aquello que no va a ocupar.

En resumen. Es mas eficiente para el mantenimiento tener solo una aplicación que te permita gestionar la carga perezosa y la seguridad.

Cabe señalar que el mantenimiento se vuelve más difícil en múltiples proyectos.